# Plain subtraction operation with 8 bits

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, bitflags, intel-8080

This is my code:

```
init:
    ; expected to go in "zero" part
    mvi a, 0ah
    mvi e, 05h
    ; content of reg b is "251"

    ; expected to go in "zero" part
    ;mvi a, 0ah
    ;mvi e, 0ah
    ; if followed two are commented out content of reg b is "254"


    ; expected to go in "minus" part
    ;mvi a, 0ah
    ;mvi e, 03h
    ; if followed two are commented out content of reg b is "254"


    ; expected to go in "minus" part
    ;mvi a,0ah
    ;mvi e,0bh
    ; if followed two are commented out content of reg b is "255"

subtractionLoop:
    sub e
    jp subtractionLoop
    jz zero
    jm minus

minus:
    mvi b, 0ffh
    ; print value as 255 to see it comes within "minus" part
    ; the part means last result is minus, so we can get remainder by adding
    ; content of reg E only one time
    hlt

zero:
    mvi b, 0bh
    ; print value as 11 to see it comes within "zero" part
    hlt
```

I simply try to achieve simple division, but I get different and interesting results as you read on comments(`;`).

**My idea is as following:**
So long as the dividend is positive, `subtractionLoop` goes on subtraction. If it hits to `0`, go to the zero part. Otherwise, go to the minus part.

Where is/are my mistake/s?
The jumps don't seem right.

Comment: Since you are getting values that are impossible given your code, I'd say you are reading the result wrong.

Comment: @Jester what about my algorithm steps as well as jumps??

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens:

1. `mvi a, 0ah`

   `a` is set 10.
2. `mvi e, 05h`

   `e` is set to 5.
3. `sub e`

   `a` is set to 10 - 5, that is, 5.
   The sign flag is dropped, meaning the result is not negative.
4. `jp subtractionLoop`

   Jumps back to `sub e`.
5. `sub e` (again)

   `a` is set to 5 - 5 = 0.
   The sign flag is still dropped.
6. `jp subtractionLoop`

   Moves control back to `sub e` once again.
7. `sub e`

   `a` is set to 0 - 5 = -5, which unsigned value is 256 - 5 = 251.
   The sign flag is raised this time.

So my guess is that it is the value of the `a` register you are looking at when you see `251`, and not the value of the `b` register.

Note that the `jz` jump will never actually pass control to `zero:` as zero result in `a` would leave the sign flag dropped and so the preceding `jp` instruction will do its job jumping to the beginning of the cycle.